# Identification of Aircraft, Weimar, Germany, May, 1945

Tags: world-war-two, military, nazi-germany, identification, aircraft

Identification of Aircraft, Weimar, Germany, May, 1945.

[image]<sup>ck.imgur.com/S83TI.jpg</sup>

Comment: Additional photo at https://www.flickr.com/photos/photolibrarian/25765489610/in/dateposted/

Comment: They look like DFS 230 Attack Gliders

Comment: @CGCampbell - I'd upvote that if you posted it as an answer - I doubt they could be anything else.

Comment: I certainly am not seeing any means of propulsion.

Answer (score 10):

They appear to be DFS (Deutsche Forschungsanstalt für Segelflug) 230 Assault Gliders, with the wings removed. There is a [great page here](http://fallschirmjager.net/Vehicles/DFS230/index.html), with some photos, and a [page for a kit form toy model here](http://www.olddogsplanes.com/230.html).

Here is one of the better photos:

[image: DFS 230 Assault Glider]
<sup>Foto: Stocker (1943)</sup>

According to the page I linked above:

> The DFS 230 was a Luftwaffe assault glider, developed by the Deutsche Forschungsanstalt für Segelflug (German Research Institute for Sailplane Flight). Hans Jacobs was the lead designer.
>
> It was intended for paratrooper assault operations, carrying ten soldiers with equipment or a payload of about 1,200 kg. The usual tug was a JU-52 but photos exist showing tugs as varied as Ju-87 and Ju-88's.
>
> DFS-230 gliders were used famously and successfully in the assaults at Eben-Emael and in the rescue at Gran Sasso of Benito Mussolini.